# Is it possible to reset specific item in Apollo Client Cache?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a query which uses fetchMore and the `relayPagination` which works fine for lazy loading when using the variables `page` and `perPage`, the issue now is I'm trying to refresh the query whenever i update the other variables for filtering like `date` and `type` which values can be either `debited` or `credited`. It fetches the data, but then appends the incoming data to apollo cache instead of replacing the old data with the new one.

for example in this sample typePolicy

```
   PaginatedBooks: {
      fields: {
        allBooks: {
          merge: relayPagination()
        }
      }
   }
   AllProducts: {
    // Singleton types that have no identifying field can use an empty
     // array for their keyFields.
     keyFields: [],
   },
```

I only want to reset `PaginatedBooks`

I've tried use fetchPolicy of `no-cache` but this stops pagination and fetchMore from working as i can't merging existing and incoming data. I opted to use `client.resetStore()`: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/core/ApolloClient/#ApolloClient.resetStore

but this also refetches other active queries and causes the ui to flicker. So far looking through the documentation and github repo I can't seem to find anything or anyone who has tried to do something similar, so I'm hoping I can get some insight and probably be offered a better solution. Thanks in advance

Comment: Curious to hear if you found any solution. Let us know what you landed on :)

Comment: @jnotelddim I got around my issues by splitting large queries on the page into separate requests and adding the `no-cache` policy on them, while the query that would need to be reset had the `cache-and-network` policy